# Using Move Constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

I wrote the class below and I have a question about it. The function `sayHello()` returns an object which is going to be destroyed after that line. However, it doesn't use move constructor. Isn't it an rvalue reference? Why it doesn't use move constructor?

```
class FString {
private:
    char *ptr;
public:
    FString() : ptr(nullptr) {}

    FString(const char *str) {
        cout << "Called: FString(const char *str)\n";
        //...
    }

    ~FString() {
        cout << "Called: ~FString()\n";
        //...
    }

    FString(FString &&s) {
        cout << "Called: FString(FString &&s)\n";
        //...
    }
};


FString sayHello() {
    FString s("Hello World!");
    return s;
}

int main() {
    FString s("Hello World!");
    FString s2(sayHello());
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Called: FString(const char *str)
Called: FString(const char *str)
Called: ~FString()
Called: ~FString()
```

Thanks.

Comment: Check this [disable optimization](http://rextester.com/QHC64283)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The move is elided; that's an optimisation allowed in various situations, even if (as here) the move constructor has side effects, so that omitting the call changes the program's behaviour.

Specifically, when the program uses a temporary (or a local variable, when returning from a function) to directly initialise an object of the same type, that move can be omitted by using the same storage for both objects. This happens here, both when using the `s` within `sayHello` to initialise the return value, and when using that value to initialise `s2`, so no move or copy constructor is needed.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler optimizes away the need for a move constructor. Have you tried disabling optimization and checking whether the result is the same?